# How to add a set of values to an existing data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, dplyr

I have a data frame containing three columns: *ID, year, growth*. The last one contains data of growth in milimeters for each year.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=rep(c("CHC01", "CHC02", "CHC03"), each=4), 
                 year=rep(2015:2018, 3), 
                 growth=c(NA, 2.3, 2.1, 3.0, NA, NA, NA, 3.2, NA, NA, 2.1, 1.2))
```

In another data frame, I have other three columns: *ID, missing_length, missing_years*. Missing length relates to the estimated length missed in the measurements.  Missing years relates to the number of missing years in *df*

```
estimate <- data.frame(ID=c("CHC01", "CHC02", "CHC03"), 
                       missing_length=c(1.0, 4.4, 3.5), 
                       missing_years=c(1,3,2))
```

For calculating the growth for each missing year, I tried:

```
missing <- rep(estimate$missing_length / estimate$missing_years, estimate$missing_years)
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to deal with this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a join and then `replace` the `NA` with the calculated value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   left_join(estimate) %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   transmute(year, growth  = replace(growth, is.na(growth), 
                 missing_length[1]/missing_years[1]))
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#   ID     year growth
#   <fct> <int>  <dbl>
# 1 CHC01  2015   1   
# 2 CHC01  2016   2.3 
# 3 CHC01  2017   2.1 
# 4 CHC01  2018   3   
# 5 CHC02  2015   1.47
# 6 CHC02  2016   1.47
# 7 CHC02  2017   1.47
# 8 CHC02  2018   3.2 
# 9 CHC03  2015   1.75
#10 CHC03  2016   1.75
#11 CHC03  2017   2.1 
#12 CHC03  2018   1.2
```

Or with `coalesce`

```
df %>%
   mutate(growth = coalesce(growth,  with(estimate, 
        setNames(missing_length/missing_years, ID))[as.character(ID)])) %>%
   as_tibble
# A tibble: 12 x 3
#   ID     year growth
#   <fct> <int>  <dbl>
# 1 CHC01  2015   1   
# 2 CHC01  2016   2.3 
# 3 CHC01  2017   2.1 
# 4 CHC01  2018   3   
# 5 CHC02  2015   1.47
# 6 CHC02  2016   1.47
# 7 CHC02  2017   1.47
# 8 CHC02  2018   3.2 
# 9 CHC03  2015   1.75
#10 CHC03  2016   1.75
#11 CHC03  2017   2.1 
#12 CHC03  2018   1.2
```

---

Or similar option in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[estimate, growth := fcoalesce(growth, 
           missing_length/missing_years), on = .(ID)]
```

Comment: Thank you akrun, it was very helpful!
While I was applying your suggestions I noticed something I forgot to point out in my example (I will explain this based on my real data, I think it will make more sense): 

All my inviduals are dated from 1835 to 2018, but some are younger than others.  For the oldest individual, I'll have no NA, because it was born in 1835 and it was alive until 2018. However, younger individuals will have, for example, 30 NA on the same column. (I'll add an example to the original question). Could you help me figure out how to deal with it, please?

Comment: I edited the example data frames from my question. Now we have something closer to my actual data. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @IsabelaM can you please post as a new question

Comment: Sure! Would it be better if I edit this question back to the first version?

Comment: @IsabelaM can you please update with the expected output as well so that i can crosscheck.  I tried with your new example, it is not giving any errors though

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution. Supposing tables "df" and "estimate" are sorted by id (ascending CHC) and we keep your "missing" object, this should work :

```
df$growth=replace(df$growth,which(is.na(df$growth)),missing)
```

Output :

```
      ID year   growth
1  CHC01 2015 1.000000
2  CHC01 2016 2.300000
3  CHC01 2017 2.100000
4  CHC01 2018 3.000000
5  CHC02 2015 1.466667
6  CHC02 2016 1.466667
7  CHC02 2017 1.466667
8  CHC02 2018 3.200000
9  CHC03 2015 1.750000
10 CHC03 2016 1.750000
11 CHC03 2017 2.100000
12 CHC03 2018 1.200000
```